# NOOBS install menu options greyed out

Tags: boot, software-installation, noobs, archlinux

I am trying to install Arch Linux using NOOBS. I have put it onto a 16GB SD card and applied power to the Pi (Pi 2, model B) and it started with no problems. However, all the menu options (Edit config, Wifi networks, Online help, Exit) are greyed out. The Install option naturally becomes available when I select one of the two available OSs (Raspbian and LibreELEC).

How can I unlock these to connect to the internet and install Arch Linux? I am not using the standard internet adapter (I'm using one from LOTEKOO) but it has worked with my Pi in the past (Raspbian installed via NOOBS).

Comment: Please update your post with the actual Raspberry Pi version. What are you using instead of "the standard internet adapter"? What did it work with before and was that NOOBS? It sounds like the NOOBS version you have does not know how to talk to your internet adapter.

Comment: @RichardChambers Done.

Comment: What model number is the LOTEKOO and what speed? Please be specific as possible. And please update your post and do not use a comment with this info.

Comment: Also see this article that in section about NOOBS mentions ""NOOBS-supported WiFi adapter" and the article mentions that the "official dongle appears to be based on a Broadcom BCM43143 chip" the two LOTEKOO dongles I see on Amazon show " Ralink 5370 Chipset" for https://www.amazon.com/150Mbps-Adapter-LOTEKOO-Wireless-Raspberry/dp/B06Y2HKT75  and "RTL8192EU Chipset" for https://www.amazon.com/300Mbps-Adapter-LOTEKOO-Wireless-Network/dp/B06Y24GDR8

Comment: @RichardChambers I don't remember the model number but I found it on Amazon: https://www.amazon.com/150Mbps-Adapter-LOTEKOO-Wireless-Raspberry/dp/B06Y2HKT75/

Comment: According to the Amazon post, that dongle uses the "Ralink 5370 Chipset"
 which may not be compatible with the requirements for NOOBS even though it works with Raspbian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless NOOBS has been changed, this is not possible. (This is due to compression used by Arch.)

If you want to run Arch, I suggest you give [PINN](https://github.com/procount/pinn/blob/master/README_PINN.md) a try.

PINN is derived from NOOBS, and performs similar functions, but has most of the bugs squashed, a vast range of choices of distribution and has a number of additional features to make image maintenance easier.

I don't know if this will solve your dongle problem.